# iPhone MoveMe Example - trouble with DisplayStrings

Tags: iphone, string

I'm starting to play a bit with iPhone applications and I downloaded the MoveMe example from the apple web page.

I managed to run the app, however I do not get the strings displayed. I noticed that the DisplayStrings.strings file, although it exists in the app folder, does not appear as one of the resources.

I tried adding it as a resource, but then after compiling I get an error saying "copystrings failed with exit code 1". I cannot find anything online regarding what the origin of this problem is...

The file itself is in utf16 (big endian), and contains simply a list of strings separated by new lines.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and as a workaround I renamed DisplayStrings.strings to DisplayStrings.data and added it as a resource. I then modified init in PlacardView.m to use the new filename. This made Xcode happy.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding the DisplayStrings.strings file as a resource.  However, when you do this it defaults the type to 'text.plist.strings' which is incorrect, since the file is just text.   So, right click on the DisplayStrings.strings file in resources and change the type to 'text'.  This solved the problem for me.